# Error when I call zip class

Tags: php, zip

If I use in simple files, the class zip works perfectly, but inside a class like below, I have an error. I forget something?

how to resolve this ?

Thank you.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zip' not found in /home/www/boutique/includes/Apps/WebService/ChatBot/Sites/Admin/Pages/Home/Actions/ChatBot/ExportZip.php:32
```

A part of my class

```
  namespace Apps\WebService\ChatBot\Sites\Admin\Pages\Home\Actions\Chatbot;

  use \OM\Registry;
  use OM\OSCOM;


  class ExportZip extends \OM\PagesActionsAbstract {
    public function execute()  {

      $OSCOM_ChatBot = Registry::get('ChatBot');
      $OSCOM_Language = Registry::get('Language');

      $transfer_directory = OSCOM::getConfig('dir_root', 'Shop') . 'includes/Work/google_ai/';

      $languages = $OSCOM_Language->getLanguages();


      $Zip = new Zip();




      $intent_file = 'my_zip_file' . '-' . date('YmdHis') . '.zip';

      $Qapps = $OSCOM_ChatBot->db->prepare('select p.products_id,
                                                    p.products_image,
                                                    pd.products_name,
                                                    pd.products_description_summary
                                            from :table_products p,
                                                  :table_products_description pd
                                            where p.products_id = pd.products_id
                                            and p.products_archive = 0
                                            and p.products_status = 1
                                            and p.products_view =1                                           
                                          ');
      $Qapps->bindInt(':products_id', (int)$OSCOM_Language->getId());
      $Qapps->execute();

      $apps = $Qapps->fetchAll();

      $result = $Zip->open($transfer_directory . $intent_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you class is in a namespace you must use the Zip class fully qualified name, i.e. have a proper use statment

Comment: I tried with use ZIP and / or $Zip = new \Zip(); but does'nt work. Do you are another idea. The zip library is installed.

Comment: Which library are you referring?

Comment: ZIP I installed like that apt-get php-zip (native)

Comment: Are you sure the class is Zip and not ZipArchive?